# Set and use value in linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm filtering `PropertyInfo` list like this:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in 
            ClassUtils.GetProperties(patternType).
            Where(pi => pi.GetCustomAttribute<TemplateParamAttribute>() != null).
            OrderBy(pi1 => pi1.GetCustomAttribute<TemplateParamAttribute>().Order))
{
    TemplateParamAttribute attr = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<TemplateParamAttribute>();
...
```

This works correctly, but I'm not satisified with 3 `GetCustomAttribute` calls in each iteration. Is there a way to reduce number of `GetCustomAttribute` calls (and still use linq)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to reduce number of GetCustomAttribute calls (and still use linq)?

Absolutely - perform a projection early on. I would do this in a query declared *before* the foreach loop though, for readability:

```
var query = from property in ClassUtils.GetProperties(patternType)
            let attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<TemplateParamAttribute>()
            where attribute != null
            orderby attribute.Order
            select new { property, attribute };

foreach (var result in query)
{
    // Use result.attribute and result.property
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query, it uses the `let` keyword which declares an anonymous type.

```
var select = from propertyInfo in typeof (ClassUtils).GetProperties(patternType)
             let attr = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<TemplateParamAttribute>()
             where attr != null
             orderby attr.Order
             select propertyInfo;
foreach (var propertyInfo in select)
{
    //Operate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
foreach(TemplateParamAttribute attr in
    ClassUtils.GetProperties(patternType).
        Select(pi => pi.GetCustomAttribute<TemplateParamAttribute()).
        Where(pa => pa != null).
        OrderBy(pa.Order))
 {
      // Use attr
 }
```

And if you need access to both the property and the attributes within the loop, you can do this:

```
foreach(var info in
    ClassUtils.GetProperties(patternType).
        Select(pi => new {prop = pi, attr = pi.GetCustomAttribute<TemplateParamAttribute()}).
        Where(pia => pia.attr != null).
        OrderBy(pia.attr.Order))
 {
      // Use info.prop and info.attr
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Your second snippet is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Filip: Except that it doesn't actually compile... you need a `new` to create an the anonymous type instance.

Comment: Note that this is basically the same as my answer - I just happen to find the query expression version easier to read. YMMV, of course :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I noticed its the same as your solution. In the end I used your version (its definitely more readable) but I marked this as answer because JLRishe answered 4 seconds before you. Now when I write that down I'm not sure it was a right thing to do. Anyway, I'll search meta for advise on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using anything else than `GetCustomAttribute` with your `propertyInfo` object:

```
foreach (TemplateParamAttribute attr in ClassUtils.GetProperties(patternType)
    .Select(pi => pi.GetCustomAttribute<TemplateParamAttribute>())
    .Where(a => a != null)
    .OrderBy(a => a.Order))
{
}
```

Comment: @ChrisF `attr` is available in the loop.

Comment: @JLRishe - oops. I meant `propertyInfo`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid several `GetCustomAttribut` calls you can introduce new range variable `tpa` for your query. Also if you need only attribute in your loop, then get your custom attributes and iterate over them:

```
var attributes = from pi in ClassUtils.GetProperties(patternType)
                 let tpa = pi.GetCustomAttribute<TemplateParamAttribute>()
                 where tpa != null 
                 orderby tpa.Order
                 select tpa;

foreach(TemplateParamAttribute attr in attributes)
{
    // ...
}
```